# What are the differences between the maxOf() and max() methods in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am a little confused by the different use-cases of the methods. I can see that one is in `Kotlin.math` and one in `Kotlin.comparisons`, so I would guess that implies `maxOf()` can be used with objects of user-defined classes, but is that the only differentiating factor?

Comment: The [maxOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/max-of.html) function has many more overloads. This means more types can be compared, including those that implement `Comparable` or even any type as long as you give a `Comparator`. There are also overloads that accept varargs, meaning you can get the max of an arbitrary number of arguments. In contrast, [max](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/max.html) is much more limited, both in number of arguments and types of arguments. But I do not know why both APIs exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps knowing the history here can help.

In Kotlin 1.1, `minOf` and `maxOf` [got added as their own separate feature](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew11.html#minof-and-maxof). I think the idea is that you are supposed to use this in rather non-mathematical situations. After all, the example they gave was:

```
val list1 = listOf("a", "b")
val list2 = listOf("x", "y", "z")
val minSize = minOf(list1.size, list2.size)
val longestList = maxOf(list1, list2, compareBy { it.size })
```

Imagine just trying to write some readable code, putting the word "of" in there just makes the line a tad bit more English-y.

Later, in Kotlin 1.2, [they added a whole lot of math constants and functions into the standard library](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew12.html#math-operations-in-kotlin-stdlib), and called the package `kotlin.math`. Since `min` and `max` *are also mathematical functions*, they also added `min` and `max`.

This is just my opinion, but compared to `minOf` and `maxOf`, `min` and `max` would be more readable if you put them inside a more complex mathematical expression. It'd make the whole thing look more like math, rather than English.

Functionally, they behave the same, and as you said, `minOf` and `maxOf` also works for any `Comparable` things, or anything at all if you provide a `Comparator`. This is because `minOf` and `maxOf` is not strictly designed for mathematical situations, whereas `min` and `max` *are*.

Notice that in Kotlin 1.4, vararg versions of `maxOf` and `minOf` also got added, but not for `min` and `max`. Again this is because the *mathematical* `min` and `max` conventionally only take two arguments.